# Unable to figure out why Xcode simulator is not working expectably

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[screenshot of the story board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtBZP.png)I am a new student learning swift for ios development in Udemy.com. I am following one of the examples to create a button which can turn the screen colour from white to red; however, I don't understand why the ios simulator is not showing me what is suppose to happen. Instead, it's just showing me a black screen. Thank you in advanced.[screenshot of the ios simulator after launched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkpxD.png)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



}

@IBOutlet weak var myBotton: UIButton!

@IBAction func MyBottonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: have you set Initialview controller ?\

Comment: If you are using storyboards, the main storyboard may have been "disconnected". Since you are just starting out, I'd say just create a new project and worry about it later.

Comment: @ hola Sir, I created this project two days ago. By the way, I have a "stack view" warning in my compiler that I have no idea how to fix

Comment: can u share the screenshot of your storyboard.

Comment: @ dRAGONAIR Yes sir, I uploaded it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no problem with the simulator, you have problem in connecting your outlets or actions. be sure that your outlets or actions are connected to the view, in your storyboard.

and the other thing you must take care of is to set entry point for your storyboard. the black you screen you mention ususally caused by these reasons

[image]

Comment: I uploaded my screenshot could you please help me take a look what's wrong

Comment: upload a photo from your storyboard, and click on the Viewcontroller then in the right box click on the connection inspector , it is the last tab with an arrow icon, like my image. @JackDu

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and run once again
In xcode command+shift+k

Comment: Sir, please allow me to ask what is the clean project for? I have never use this feature before.

Comment: I did it, and still not working, it gives me a warning says the size and position is ambiguous for "stack view"

Comment: if you are using storyboard check u have given the storyboard entry point for main storyboard